# Conversation scope in Stripes Framework

Tags: java, stripes, conversation-scope

I am currently stuck with using the [Stripes Framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home).

I haven't used it in years, and I've gotten used to the features of other frameworks.
One thing I miss is a conversation (or browser window) scope. Is there a way to implement that in Stripes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used `Stripes`. By googling I have found that there is a sort of wizard functionality: [link](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Wizard+Forms). Hope it helps you:)

Comment: yes, I had seen that. The thing is, I don't need a wizard functionality, and I don't have fixed start and end points. I just need a way to set and retrieve variables in a scope that's between request and session.

Comment: @Sean - I think every conversation(at least `Seam` ones) have start and end points.

Comment: @Sean - Apart from that `Wizard`, I doubt that there is a scope different than the standard ones:(

Comment: @Sean - I guess we are back to abusing the good old session:P